# APEX 5.1 Open external site page in new window

Tags: oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I am working on APEX 5.1 application and want to get report in a new window when click on the button. Report is made using iReport 5.6.0 and hosted on JasperServer 6.
Button has Action property set to **Redirect to URL** and the URL is http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/flow.html? ...
I tried with ***http://url/" target="_blank*** as suggested [here](https://www.inside-oracle-apex.com/opening-url-in-new-window/) but with no success.

Is it possible to do that and, if yes, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work. Within the URL Target textarea, place the following code:

```
javascript:var x=window.open('https://URL/','_blank');
```